# how to get top 5 semantic versions if you are using Semantic Versioning in a folder

Tags: semantic-versioning

I have a folder with lot of zip files based on semantic versions i want to get the top 5 versions and delete rest. I want to know how can i query the latest top 5 versions in a query

```
        MyService- 1.0.2.5.zip
        MyService- 1.0.2.6.zip
        MyService- 1.0.2.7.zip
        MyService- 2.0.0.63.zip
        MyService- 2.0.0.64.zip
        MyService- 2.0.0.65.zip
        MyService- 2.0.0.66.zip and so on
        MyService- 3.0.0.11.zip
        MyService- 3.0.0.12.zip and so on 

        I want the top 5 or top 1 version is there any utility or function which gives me that abilitya
```

Comment: What do you mean by "query"? Folders don't support "queries". Do you want to write a program? In which language?

Comment: I want to write a program in groovy but even c# is ok, I am more keen to know the logic to get the top 5 version? is there any logic pre defined

Comment: Parse the file name to extract the version, parse the version string into a class containing major, minor and patch version numbers, group the files by their name, and for each group, sort them by version, then only keep the last 5 ones.

Comment: Pleas,provide more information. The question is impossible to answer at this moment.

Comment: MyService- 1.0.2.5.zip
            MyService- 1.0.2.6.zip
            MyService- 1.0.2.7.zip
            MyService- 2.0.0.63.zip
            MyService- 2.0.0.64.zip
            MyService- 2.0.0.65.zip
            MyService- 2.0.0.66.zip and so on
            MyService- 3.0.0.11.zip
            MyService- 3.0.0.12.zip and so on 
   
   I want the top 5 or top 1 version is there any utility or function which gives me that ability

Answer (score 0):

Searching the [Google for SemVer C#](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=voxJWuOsKJGmjwPak5TgAg&q=SemVer+C%23&oq=SemVer+C%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.1297.5343.0.6375.11.7.2.2.2.0.117.494.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.11.509...46j0i131k1j0i46k1.0.BgaHAhHgEGM), yields a couple of .NET libraries and other related information.  The [Google also list some Java libraries](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=qY1JWqy1PNjQjwO4mKq4Cg&q=semver+java+library&oq=SemVer+Java&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0l3j0i22i30k1.1444.8170.0.10533.11.9.0.2.2.0.79.437.9.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.11.444...46j0i131k1j0i46k1.0.Ehn_CgbmW2M).

As for the algorithm, sort the list using the SemVer precedence semantics, specified in [SemVer Specification #11](https://semver.org/#semantic-versioning-specification-semver), then pick the first N items in the list.